# Error in SQL Server 2012 OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given the following SQL code against the AdventureWorks Database:

```
begin transaction;

drop trigger Sales.iduSalesOrderDetail;
alter table Sales.SalesOrderDetail
    add LineNumber int null;
go

with sod as (
    select
        SalesOrderID, 
            /* other cols */
        LineNumber,
        NewLineNumber = row_number() over 
            (partition by SalesOrderID order by SalesOrderDetailID) + 1
    from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
    where SalesOrderID <= 44000)
update sod
set LineNumber = NewLineNumber,
    ModifiedDate = getdate()
output
    inserted.SalesOrderID, 
    /* other cols */
    inserted.LineNumber;

select
    SalesOrderID, 
    /* other cols */
    LineNumber
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where SalesOrderID <= 44000;

rollback transaction;
```

When running this code on SQL Server 2008R2, it runs fine; that is to say, it updates the data in `Sales.SalesOrderDetail` and outputs the results, which match the data from the following SELECT statement.

However, when running this code on SQL Server 2012, I get the message:

> Msg 4196, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   
> Column 'deleted.NewLineNumber' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains an expression using a window function.

This is odd because I am not referencing deleted.NewLineNumber in any way.  I have attempted removing various OUTPUT columns and get the same result.  The only two ways I have found to stop the error have been to

- make the NewLineNumber column be exactly the result of the `row_number()` (that is to say: `NewLineNumber = row_number() over (...)`); or
- remove the OUTPUT clause altogether.

Is this possibly a bug in how SQL Server is processing the expressions in the CTE? Has anyone else run into this?

I'm working on possible workarounds, but I am curious about this.

Comment: I presume something to do with the fix here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/682645/wrong-results-unhandled-exception-using-deleted-in-the-output-clause#details

Comment: Looks like someone has now raised this issue here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779077/output-clause-fails-when-doing-update-using-cte#details

Comment: Yes - I raised the issue at MS connect after hearing from Aaron below and from other people at MS TechNet.

Comment: As for the other ticket, I believe that it is related.  I would presume that when they fixed the problem listed in that ticket, they created the problem I'm running into.  I agree that the problem given by the original ticket is a valid bug and should be fixed.  However, I think they may have been a little overzealous in preventing it, as I see no reason why this one should not work, especially seeing as it works fine with the +1 in the set clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in SQL Server 2012, and will be fixed in SP2:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779077/output-clause-fails-when-doing-update-using-cte

A workaround is to remove the `+ 1` from the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation; this spurious error message goes away. Rewrite this portion:

```
  NewLineNumber = row_number() over 
    (partition by SalesOrderID order by SalesOrderDetailID)
    ---------------- remove the +1 here --------------------^^^
  from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
  where SalesOrderID <= 44000)
update sod 
  set LineNumber = NewLineNumber + 1,
  ------- and put it here -------^^^
```

Comment: Hmm... very interesting.  All the more reason to think this might be a bug in the query engine.  I've put in a note at the tech forums to see if maybe the MS people know anything more.  This is probably enough for me to jerry-rig a workaround for my project though. Thanks!

Comment: @Stuart I have some contacts that I'm pinging as well. I don't think this is a bug per se, I just think the error message is slightly misleading (it shouldn't talk about `deleted`). But I would like to get an explanation about why the workaround works simply by moving the location of the addition.

Comment: @Stuart it is in fact a bug, and will be fixed in 2012 SP2 (ETA unknown): https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779077/output-clause-fails-when-doing-update-using-cte The workaround is trivial so it is unlikely pestering PSS will get you a hot fix any faster.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.  This is the feedback I posted, and I was grateful to hear from them that they had already fixed it.  Yes, the workaround is easy, but will require a bit of ugly code in my project.  Right or wrong, I am building a SQL string in my project on the fly (though with parameters for user provided data; thankfully I'm not a moron).  The original pattern is easy to abstract as "provide the definition of sod and we'll update from there".  The new pattern requires I provide the update statement as well.